# Simulate Form Submit with Symfony 2

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm working with Symfony 2 and need some advice.

I have a Controller, which gets a form-request and searches the database for matches and renders the results (so it's just a basic search).
Now I would like to redirect to this controller but without coming from a form.

To be more specific:

- I'm on the search-page, fill out the form and hit the search button -> I get results for my search.
- I'm somewhere else and want to delete a labelCategory of a book -> If some books still use this labelCategory, I want to get search results for this labelCategory.

My only idea so far is, to simulate the form submit somehow, but I didn't find out how to do it.

I'd be happy for every help of you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need form submit at all. Just put logic of searching to separate class. Than you can it in any controller you want. Maybe [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) doc can help to

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Not exactly the solution to my problem since I already separated the search-part from the action but it gave me the right idea:
My motivation was, to reuse the rendering of the search results, because I didn't want to write the functions for generating page-numbers again, only slightly modified for a new controller. So I generalized and decoupled them from the controller to make use of them from any other controller.

Comment: So, simulating form submit for Symfony hasn't been answered?  Anyone?